# Deleted files in "state" deleted on debian

Tags: linux, debian

The command :

```
lsof | grep 'deleted'
```

shows me lots of files from log and tmp directories

```
apache2     770   www-data   12w      REG                9,1     148346    1049155 /var/log/apache2/myurl.com-error.log (deleted)
python     3012      plone   11u      REG                9,1  134217728     393442 /tmp/tmpINz4Xl (deleted)
```

Some of them weigh heavily

They come from apache logs or python things from plone CMS

How to definitively delete them ?

Answer (score 1):

Shut down the process which still has the file open. In this case, you'll want to shut down apache2, pid 770, and python, pid 3012.

Comment: Is it normal that some logs have the same pid but are not deleted ?

Comment: Yes. One process may open up multiple files. Linux lets you delete a file in use, but it doesn't get removed until the last process is done with it.